# Direct reference to Object property in Global scope

Tags: javascript

Whenever I try to execute following code in console, it prints 2. Can someone please clarify what does this mean.

```
var bar = 1,
foo = {};

foo: {
 bar: 2;
 baz: ++bar;
};
```

Comment: It just prints you the last evaluated value.

Comment: `++bar` is the reason for that. That would be executed at last in the above given code. And it returns 2.